# Angular directive fields not require brackets

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using UI Bootstrap's datepicker function and I'd like to get ahold of one of the values passed into an attribute.

```
// JS
$scope.myMaxDate = new Date();

<!-- HTML -->
<input datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" max-date="myMaxDate" />
```

I don't understand why in this case the `max-date` attr takes a string rather than an expression like `{{myMaxDate}}`.  How is it getting a hold of the actual value?

What's more, I'm using a decorator to alter some data from this directive and would like to access this attribute but all I get is the string `myMaxDate`.

```
    $provide.decorator("datepickerPopupDirective", ["$delegate", function($delegate) {
        // get references to the directive and old link function
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        var link = directive.link;

        // create a new link function using compile
        directive.compile = function() {
            // the new link function we want to return
            return function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                console.log(attrs.maxDate); // 'myMaxDate'

                // invoke the old link function
                link.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer your question on how the `datepicker-popup` directive finds the actual value of the `max-date` attribute, it most likely uses the `$eval` method of the `scope`.

So in your code, to see the actual value use:

```
 console.log(scope.$eval(attrs.maxDate));
```

This is also why the directive doesn't require double curly brackets. In fact double curly brackets will cause problems because it will convert your `myMaxDate` object to a string and consequently lose the `Date` object's methods.

For more information on the `$eval` method look at the [AngularJS Scope API](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope)

Answer (score 0):

For starters you're overriding `compile` in its entirety. That would create potential problems.

```
 $provide.decorator("datepickerPopupDirective", ["$delegate", function($delegate) {
        // get references to the directive and old link function
        var directive = $delegate[0];
        var compile = directive.compile;

        directive.compile = function() {

            var link = compile.apply(this, arguments); 

            // the new link function we want to return
            return function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
                console.log(attrs.maxDate); // 'myMaxDate'

                // invoke the old link function
                link.apply(this, arguments);
            };
        };

....
```

Comment: Wouldn't this overwrite the existing `link` method?

Comment: No because link is a function that can be returned from a compile, and the old link (and its compile result) are being saved similar to what you  had previously.