# Why angular expressions evaluate to empty strings in an attribute

Tags: angularjs, scope, expression

When an element's attribute contains more than one angular expression those expressions evaluate to empty strings. In my example I have an attribute with 2 identical expressions and both of them simply output scope variables. If I remove one expression then the other expression evaluates correctly. What am I missing?

Extract from the controller:

```
$http.get(
    "http://myurl/odata/Profile",
    {
        params: {
            "$orderby": "Id",
            "someParamId": "10"
        }
    }
).success(function (response) {
        $scope.data = response.value;
        $scope.mytest = "hello";
        $scope.dataRead = true;
    }
);
```

Extract from the directive:

```
    link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
        scope.$watch("dataRead", function (dataAvailable) {
            if (dataAvailable) {
                ...here I check for mytest attribute value...
```

Extract from my html:

```
     <my-directive id="someId" style="position: absolute; background-color:bisque;" width="200" mytest="{{mytest}}{{mytest}}"....
```

In the example above if mytest has that expression twice the resulting value is an empty string, otherwise it evaluates correctly. 
So essentially once there's more than 1 scope variable expression within the same attribute value it fails to evaluate.

Desperately need help!

**EDITED:**

Apologies for the late edit. Here's the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/svZtSp00DaGK3HWUYB7R?p=preview) that shows the problem. There's an attribute myattr in the index.html page. It deliberately has it's value set to two identical expressions. In the directive's link function however this attribute's value is an empty string.

Comment: The code is incomplete. We have no idea how the directive is defined, what is supposed to evaluate, to what, where the evaluation is displayed, etc. Post a complete minimal example reproducing the problem. Explain what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: Create a plunkr/jsbin/whatever with your issue. It's working fine in this one: http://jsbin.com/mupuhi/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: Yes, sorry for not giving you enough information and for the delay in responding. Here's the plunkr with the reproducible conditions: [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/svZtSp00DaGK3HWUYB7R?p=preview) 

As you can see the span element does properly evaluate but if you look at the myattr attribute it's set to an empty string - an alert box shows that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems with your code.

First, as I said in [Angular directive fields not require brackets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33663058/angular-directive-fields-not-require-brackets/33677152#33677152). Double curly brackets in directive fields cause problems. You should use Angular expressions instead.

Problematic HTML

```
<body ng-controller="myViewCtrl">
                      <!-- this is a problem -->
    <my-directive myattr="{{mytest}}{{mytest}}"></my-directive>
    <span>{{mytest}}{{mytest}}</span>
</body>
```

Instead use:

```
<body ng-controller="myViewCtrl">
    <my-directive myattr="mytest+mytest"></my-directive>
    <span>{{mytest}}{{mytest}}</span>
</body>
```

**Second Problem**

To see the computed value of the attribute, you need to use the `$eval` method of the scope.

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch("loaded", function(loaded) {
        if (loaded) {
          //Do this
          alert(scope.$eval(attrs.myattr));
          //Not this
          //alert(attrs.myattr);
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

To learn more about the `$eval` method, see the [AngularJS $rootScope.Scope API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope).

**Note to readers**

The directives `ng-src`, `ng-srcset`, and `ng-href` are interpolated and work with double curly brackets. Most other attribute directives use `$eval` to evaluate Angular expressions and will not work with double curly brackets.

Double curly brackets sometimes work in directives and sometimes are necessary. It depends how a directive is implemented. So the definitive answer is it depends.

Comment: Thanks for the example @georgeawg, however it's unrelated. See my comment in the original post.

Comment: @Nikolai edited the answer with snips and corrections from your code

Comment: It was that easy???! :-$ Das ist fantastische!!! Thank you my friend! Removing curly brackets and evaluating using $eval did the job nicely!

Comment: However @georgeawg, just out of interest, why the same expression would evaluate correctly if $scope.mytest is set outside of the **then** function: 

`app.controller('myViewCtrl', function($scope, jsonService) {

  $scope.mytest = 'Bzzz';
  jsonService.getjson().then(function(d) {
        $scope.sourceData = d;
        $scope.loaded = true;
  });

});`

try it in plunker and you'll see that myattr will evaluate correctly

Comment: That is another question.

Comment: Sure, I'll ask separately. Would you upvote my question now please?